# mysql is going crazy with regexp

Tags: mysql

I'm having some problems with mysql. See the next script in which I'll create one table, insert some data, query, change the data and then query again.

Consider this script:

```
#Create the table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE `T` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `x` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` VARCHAR(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `d6fe1d0be6347b8ef2427fa629c04485` (`x`),
  KEY `ee16755af8c89d0c26540daf7a0fe1b3` (`y`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

#Add two lines
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'login','read'), (3,'','read');

#Query 1: expected 1 line, got 1 line
SELECT * FROM T WHERE
`y` = 'read' AND
(
        ('login' = '' AND `x` = '') OR
        (`x` != '' && 'login' REGEXP `x`)
);

#Query 2: expected 1 line, got 2 line
SELECT * FROM T WHERE
`y` = 'read' AND
(
        ('login' = '' AND `x` = '') OR
        ('login' REGEXP `x`)
);

#Invert field x
UPDATE T SET `x` = '' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE T SET `x` = 'login' WHERE id = 3;

#Another time, Query 1: expected 1 line, got 1 line
SELECT * FROM T WHERE
`y` = 'read' AND
(
        ('login' = '' AND `x` = '') OR
        (`x` != '' && 'login' REGEXP `x`)
);

#Another time, Query 2: expected 1 line, got 1 line
SELECT * FROM T WHERE
`y` = 'read' AND
(
        ('login' = '' AND `x` = '') OR
        ('login' REGEXP `x`)
);
```

It will output:

```
id      x       y
1       login   read

id      x       y
1       login   read
3               read

id      x       y
3       login   read

id      x       y
3       login   read
```

I think that this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Reported to MySQL: verified as a bug. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66720